# how to open a new window on click event of node in ASP.Net TreeView control

Tags: asp.net, treeview, asp.net-3.5

In my application I need to open a new window form on click of a node in my `TreeView` control.

I'm working with ASP.Net 3.5 / C#.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TreeNode Value="C1" Text="Master" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC1" Text="A"></asp:TreeNode>            
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C2" Text="tempdb" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC2" Text="B"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C3" Text="Model" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC3" Text="C"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C4" Text="msdb" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC4" Text="D"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C5" Text="Projects" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC5" Text="E"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C6" Text="Examples" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC61" Text="Tables" NavigateUrl="~/ShowPDF.aspx"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC62" Text="Views" NavigateUrl="~/Str2Number.aspx"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC63" Text="Stored Procedures" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx.cs"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC64" Text="Triggers" NavigateUrl="~/Default2.aspx"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC65" Text="Functions" NavigateUrl="~/Default3.aspx"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C7" Text="AccSys" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC7" Text="G"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

<asp:TreeNode Value="C8" Text="GarSys" Expanded="False">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="CC8" Text="H"></asp:TreeNode>
</asp:TreeNode>

</Nodes>
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeNode contains an property called Url. Set the Url appropriately. But you are saying windows form in the question. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the links to open in a new browser window set the target property on the nodes to `_blank`.